# Don't arrays work as member variables in managed classes?

Tags: arrays, class, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm writing a program for opinion polls and I use the class 'Partito',

```
#pragma once

ref class Partito
{
protected:
    //System::String ^nome;
    int IndexP;             //Index Partito
    float MaxConsenso;
    float consensoTot;
    int consenso;
//workaround according to Hans Passant:
//  char Risposta[5];           
    array<int> ^Risposte;// Risposte means anwers.
//workaround end
System::Drawing::Color colore;

public:
    Partito(
        int _IndexP,
      float _consensoTot, int consenso

        array<int> ^_Risposte      // workaround

);      //costruttore

    void CalcCons(int consenso);

    float GetConsensoTot(void);
};
    };
```

Now the definitions:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Partito.h"

//Partito::Partito(void)
Partito::Partito(
              int _IndexP,
            float _consensoTot,
            int consenso
//workaround start
            array<int> ^_Risposte //workaround
//workaround end
)
{
        //char Risposta[5]; 
//workaround start
     Risposte=gcnew array<int>(5); //workaround
    Risposte=_Risposte; //workaround
//workaround end.
    IndexP =_IndexP;
    consensoTot = _consensoTot;
    MaxConsenso = 12;
}
void Partito::CalcCons(int consenso)
{

consensoTot+=(consenso*100)/MaxConsenso;
}

float Partito::GetConsensoTot(void)
{
    return consensoTot;
}
```

Now, with the workaround, the compiler accepts it without any problems. In the file "Form1h" now I can initialize the array without any problems:

```
Form1(void)
{
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: aggiungere qui il codice del costruttore.
            //
```

I define an object, inizializing the array in this way.

```
Partito^ ExampleParty = gcnew Partito(0,0,0,gcnew array<int>{0,1,2,2,0});
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no problem as shown. Please include the code that actually fails.

Comment: The code above compiles **fine**. If you have a problem, you'll have to edit the question and add the code that actually fails. You can copy-paste the code from above into a .cpp file and it will compile OK.

Comment: Show the actual source code that fails, state the name and version number of the compiler you are using, show the complete command line you use to compile, and show the complete, exact text of the error messages.

Comment: This error may occur if you mix "standard" class types with Managed C++, or whatever Microsoft calls it this week. Did you try looking up the error in the documentation?

Comment: Is Riposta a String-like value, or a list of characters?

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2008, Express Version.  The error message is:" 1>d:\documenti\uwe\visual studio 2008\projects\projectname\Partito.h(11) : error C4368: impossibile definire 'Risposta' come membro di 'Partito' gestito: tipi misti non supportati" means "mixed types not supported". Where can I find that documentation?

Answer (score 2):

This code can be boiled down to a simple example:

```
ref class foo {
public:
    int array[6];   // C4368: mixed types are not supported
};
```

What's going on here is the C++/CLI compiler saving you from shooting your leg off.  A shot that could look like this:

```
foo^ obj = gcnew foo;
NativeFunction(obj->array, 6);
```

Where NatievFunction() takes an int* as an argument.  That's deadly when the garbage collector kicks in, just as NativeFunction() is executing.  It will *move* the foo object in memory when it compacts the heap.  Making the int* invalid.  Disaster strikes when the native function now reads garbage or destroys the GC heap when it writes to the array.

Workarounds are to use int* instead of int[] so that the memory for the array is allocated from the native heap with the *new* operator and thus always stable.  Allocate it in the constructor, you will need a destructor and a finalizer to release it again.  Or to just use a managed array, an `array<int>^` in this case.  You can use pin_ptr<> to temporarily pin it if it needs to be passed to a native function.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation how the compiler prevents me to shoot my leg off. There are two terms that I haven't learnt yet: NativeFunciont() and foo. I have chosen the    array<int> solution. Just have a look at my new edit. I have marked the changes with //workaround. I don't understand Your last sentence. What is a 'Pin pointer'? Is my wourkaround ok, or are ther some "hidden dangers"? Thank You!

Comment: Stick with `array<int>`, stops you from having to grok the interop complications.

Answer (score 1):

Your char array `Riposta` is correctly declared in the header file. What you do in your constructor is to create a local char array `Riposta` of size `Ndomande`. Although I do not have a clue where that comes from.

Comment: Put it away, its a local variable that I've forgotten to delete. Sorry!